# Hide PHP Session ID from URL and COOKIE

Tags: php, session, xss, session-cookies, csrf

I would like to hide the PHPSESSID from the Cookies and also prevent it from being used in the URL as well. My purpose for this is to avoid hacking using the PHPSESSID variable. But I would want my PHP to still utilize sessions.

Comment: `But I would want my PHP to still utilize sessions` it won't be able to do so - you need somehow attach the same session to all requests, i.e. you need to provide session id with each request.

Comment: Really? or should I add a function that recreates the session manually?

Comment: and how would you know which session to give to current request from user? how do you want to identify them?

Comment: You _can not_ use sessions if you do not give the client access to an identifier of sorts (the session ID). It's like expecting someone to send you an e-mail while refusing to give them an address to reach you on.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the PHPSESSID by setting your own session id. You could obscure the value or save what your need to a file or sql before ending the session as [Cheery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164491/cheery) was getting at..in 2014. There's probably cleaner ways to do this but one approach is to call a function to extract what you need from the session before destroying it. The session will end but you could reassign the values like ...
`$_SESSION['catname'] = 'Fluffy';` see the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for more on sessions.

```
<?php//7.4.33
function log_value_to_sql_or_file(){ ... } // your business function.

if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    $important_value = filter_var($_SESSION['catname'],FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    log_value_to_sql_or_file($important_value);
    if (version_compare(phpversion(), "3.0.0", "<=")) {
        //unset for version 3 or less
        session_unset();
    }
    session_destroy(); // application thinks it ended.
}

$_SESSION = array();
$id = uniqid() . '-id';   //unique id 64252c-id
$name = uniqid() . '-name'; //unique name 64252d-name
session_id($id);
session_name($name);
session_start();     //application thinks it started.
$_SESSION['catname'] = 'Fluffy';
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. .htaccess

> php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

2. php

> ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);